# ATT Assembly to C

Tags: c, assembly, x86, att

Working on learning assembler and I have the following code I have to translate to C:

```
pushl   %ebp
movl    %esp, %ebp
movl    12(%ebp), %eax
imull   $886836204, %eax, %edx
movl    8(%ebp), %eax
addl    %edx, %eax
addl    $629084528, %eax
popl    %ebp
ret
```

I know that it takes two arguments and is in the format `int func(int1, int2) {}` and it returns something from the addition and multiplication lines. Other than that I'm lost. What does this look like in C?

Comment: @isedev indeed. that's exactly what i am thinking.

Comment: There are two ways to do it.  The first way is to emulate what the assembly instructions are doing (hint: you'll need a stack implementation and some registry variables).  The second way is to figure out what the assembly language is accomplishing, and write C code that accomplishes the same thing.  Personally, I vote for the latter approach.

Comment: then additional hint: `gcc -S` compiles C code to assembly, so you can test your theories.

Comment: Ya unfortunately....

Comment: @RobertHarvey the latter is what I'm required to do. Just trying to work it out on my own and not getting the results.

Comment: It gets a couple int params from stack and adds.... oh wait...

Answer (score 0):

I'd say `int func(int a, int b){return b*886836204+a+629084528;}`

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it's a one line return because it doesnt allocate memory on stack for local variables , but the logic seens to be like this:

```
int function(int x, int y){
    int eax;
    int edx;

    eax = x;

    edx = 886836204 * eax;

   eax = y;
   eax = eax + edx;
   eax = eax + 629084528;

return eax;
```

}

Something like this:

```
return x * 886836204 + (x + y)  + 629084528;
```